# gorm Many To Many Select gives invalid association [] error

Tags: go, many-to-many, go-gorm

This is my db schema:

users :

```
id uuid PRIMARY KEY ,   title character
"1234"                  "ABCD"
```

languages :

```
id uuid PRIMARY KEY ,   name character
"1122"                  "eng"
"1133"                  "man"
```

user_languages :

```
user_id uuid,   language_id uuid
"1234"          "1122"
"1234"          "1133"
```

This is my code:

```
type User struct {
   Id           uuid.UUID  `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
   Title        string     `json:"title"`
   Languages    []Language `json:"languages" gorm:"many2many:user_languages;"`
}

type Language struct {
   ID   uuid.UUID `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
   Name string    `json:"name"`
}

func GetUser(id string) User {
   user := User{}
   languages := Language{}

   db.Where("id = ?", id).Find(&user) 
   // SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'id' = id;

   db.Model(&user).Related(&languages) 
   // SELECT * FROM "languages" INNER JOIN "user_languages" ON "user_languages"."language_id" = "languages"."id" WHERE "user_languages"."user_id" = 111

   return user
}
```

I am expecting this result:

```
{
   "id": "1234",
   "title": "ABCD",
   "languages" : [{ 
               "id" : "1122",
               "name" : "eng"
           },{ 
               "id" : "1122",
               "name" : "eng"
           }]
}
```

But I am getting `invalid association []` on console, adding a gorm logger did not provide more information.

Even if I can only get a "languages" object like an array of languages names, this is also fine:

```
"languages" : ["eng", "man"]
```

Comment: Doesn't `db.Model(&user).Related(&languages) ` need to be `db.Model(&user).Related(user.languages)` ? I mean, even if that statement succeeded, the user object you returned would have have an empty languages array since you never assign to it, only to the local variable.

Answer (score 10):

You may try:

```
db.Model(&user).Related(&languages, "Languages")
```

More examples can be find in the [test](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/021d7b33143de37b743d1cf660974e9c8d3f80ea/multi_primary_keys_test.go)

Comment: So this worked for me too, but the documentation on the gorm website doesn't say that you have to specify the foreign key. In fact I specified the ForeignKey and AssociationForeignKey tags in my struct definition and it still didn't work without explicitly adding the column name in the `Related` API...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `Association`. You can also get the matching user more succinctly using `db.First(&user, id)`.

```
func GetUser(id string) User {
    var user User

    db.First(&user, id)

    db.Model(&user).Association("Languages").Find(&user.Languages) 

    return user
}
```

Comment: Can you explain you use `Association` instead of `Relation` ?

Comment: As far as I know `Association` is just the name for relationships in Gorm. The docs page is pretty good at getting the idea across: http://jinzhu.me/gorm/associations.html